# Find the **bases** of the trapezoid,

Tags: geometry

**Angle** of the base of the trapezoid is **23 and 67**, the line that connects the midpoints of the base of the trapezoid is **3cm**

Find the **bases** of the trapezoid, If the midline is **7cm**
[my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCcwH.png)

I failed to solve this, I don't even understand where to put the angles provided(are they supposed to be separate angles, or should they both be added and form a right angle) , I tried to graph it above, still I'd like to know how this should be solved, so i can improve, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let P be intersection of the lines CA and DB. $\angle APB=90^\circ$, because $\angle C + \angle D = 90^\circ$. In any trapezium the midpoints of bases and the point P lie on a line. In a right triangle the median to the hypotenuse is equal to half the hypotenuse.

This gives us $3 = \frac{CD-AB}{2}$. And since the midline is equal to 7, we have $7=\frac{CD+AB}{2}$.

So, $CD=10$ and $AB=4$

Comment: Thanks,if you could explain bit more about how we get  $3 = \frac{CD-AB}{2}$ ?

Comment: @bartlyajames Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. $PM=AB/2$. Let $N$ be midpoint of $CD$. $PN=CD/2$. The points $P, M, N$ lie on a line, so $MN=PN-PM$

Comment: The points P, M, N are on a line because triangles $PAB$ and $PCD$ are similar, so $PAM$ and $PCN$ are similar (by two sides and angle) and that means that $\angle APM = \angle CPN$

Comment: I understand that now, can you tell your thought process that made you think of that solution? Like bringing in the P intersection and midpoint part, or is that  something that just comes with more practice